# Passing a null view to RecyclerView.ViewHolder crashes the app when calling super

Tags: android

Since I am creating my views programmatically for my `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` I don't need to pass any view to it in `onCreateViewHolder` but when it calls through to super it crashes with this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: itemView may not be null
```

Here is some code:

```
        @Override
    public ImagePreviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ImagePreviewViewHolder(null);
    }


protected class ImagePreviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout page;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ImagePreviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView); // HERE IT CRASHES
        page = createPage();
        imageView = createImageView();
        page.addView(imageView);
    }
}
```

@DanailAlexiev, is this what you meant:

```
    @Override
    public ImagePreviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LinearLayout page = createPage();
        ImageView imageView = createImageView();
        page.addView(imageView);
        return new ImagePreviewViewHolder(page);
    }

protected class ImagePreviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    LinearLayout page;
    ImageView imageView;

    public ImagePreviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        page = (LinearLayout) itemView;
        imageView = (ImageView) page.getChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewHolder` uses the `itemView` reference internally. It can't be null.

What you should do is move your view creation logic to `onCreateViewHolder()` and pass the created view to your `ViewHolder` instance.

Comment: Ive updated my question with a code that follows your isntructions, could you confirm that's what you meant?

Comment: @J.K. Yope, this is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The point is you have to create your views *before* you can *hold* onto them. Use a factory method.

```
static class ImagePreviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout page;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public static ImagePreviewViewHolder create(ViewGroup parent) {
        // Option 1: Inflate the view hierarchy.
        final Context context = parent.getContext();
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, parent, false);
        return new ImagePreviewViewHolder(view);
    }

    public ImagePreviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        page = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.page);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}
```

I'm sure you can adapt this example to your needs where you create views programmatically.

Also note the `static` modifier on class which forces you into some healthy habits such as using the closest `Context`.

Comment: I was passing an empty parent because I didn't have a layout to inflate as I was creating my views programmatically

Comment: @J.K. You're not supposed to pass the parent in the view holder constructor. The parent is the `RecyclerView`. You need to pass a view that will represent the item.